# How to convert a Complex list in to a JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, nested-lists

I am struggling with a complex nested list that needed to convert into a JSON. I have a structure of the JSON as the output. I am finding it is very complex problem for me to solve this. So I am hoping a solution from the stackoverflow problem solvers. because there is no like question in the internet like this as I hope.

```
Sample List as input
[
   [
      "Unit : Baht",
      "2018",
      "2018",
      "2019",
      "2019",
      "2020",
      "2020"
   ],
   [
      " ",
      "Amount",
      "%Change",
      "Amount",
      "%Change",
      "Amount",
      "%Change"
   ],
   [
      "Accounts Receivable",
      "-",
      "0.00",
      "-",
      "0.00",
      "-",
      "0.00"
   ],
   [
      "Inventories",
      "-",
      "0.00",
      "-",
      "0.00",
      "-",
      "0.00"
   ],
   [
      "Total Current Assets",
      "924,724.20",
      "394.08",
      "942,724.20",
      "1.94",
      "1,234,663.71",
      "30.96"
   ],
   [
      "Total Assets",
      "924,724.20",
      "394.08",
      "942,724.20",
      "1.94",
      "1,234,663.71",
      "30.96"
   ],
   [
      "Total Current Liabilities",
      "10,000.00",
      "-49.18",
      "20,000.00",
      "100.00",
      "22,163.43",
      "10.81"
   ],
   [
      "Total Non-current Liabilities",
      "-",
      "0.00",
      "-",
      "0.00",
      "-",
      "0.00"
   ],
   [
      "Total Liabilities",
      "10,000.00",
      "-49.18",
      "20,000.00",
      "100.00",
      "22,163.43",
      "10.81"
   ],
   [
      "Equity",
      "914,724.20",
      "446.17",
      "922,724.20",
      "0.87",
      "1,212,500.28",
      "31.40"
   ],
   [
      "Total Liabilities and Equity",
      "924,724.20",
      "394.08",
      "942,724.20",
      "1.94",
      "1,234,663.71",
      "30.96"
   ]
]
```

My Structure of the JSON

```
{
   "HeadKey":[
      {
         "Accounts Receivable":[
            {
               "2018":{
                  "Amount":"-",
                  "%Change":"0.00"
               },
               "2019":{
                  "Amount":"-",
                  "%Change":"0.00"
               },
               "2020":{
                  "Amount":"-",
                  "%Change":"0.00"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Inventories":[
            {
               "2018":{
                  "Amount":"-",
                  "%Change":"0.00"
               },
               "2019":{
                  "Amount":"-",
                  "%Change":"0.00"
               },
               "2020":{
                  "Amount":"-",
                  "%Change":"0.00"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Total Current Assets":[
            {
               "2018":{
                  "Amount":"924,724.20",
                  "%Change":"394.08"
               },
               "2019":{
                  "Amount":"942,724.20",
                  "%Change":"1.94"
               },
               "2020":{
                  "Amount":"1,234,663.71",
                  "%Change":"30.96"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Total Assets":[
            {
               "2018":{
                  "Amount":"10,000.00",
                  "%Change":"-49.18"
               },
               "2019":{
                  "Amount":"20,000.00",
                  "%Change":"100.00"
               },
               "2020":{
                  "Amount":"22,163.43",
                  "%Change":"10.81"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Note: The above `JSON` is written by me. and it isn't incomplete as we can see in the list it has more but the `JSON` it isn't complete. So I need a dynamic algorithm for auto structure as the Sample `JSON`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is difficult to say as you don't have matching input and output, but I would start with : `pandas.DataFrame(your_data_in)` or perhaps `pandas.DataFrame(your_data_in).transpose()`

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a JSON file with a structure that is different from a list, I.E. You have multiple levels such as above, you will most likely need to create a dictionary object, to then convert to JSON using the `json` module.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps([1, 3])
'[1, 3]'
>>> json.dumps({"Lvl1": {"Lvl2": "Here"} })
'{"Lvl1": {"Lvl2": "Here"}}'
```

It looks like in your input data, there is the same number of elements in every item. **IF** this is **ALWAYS** true, you could loop

```
for i in range(len(input[0])):
    for item in input:
        # Do something with item[i]
```

and start building a dictionary object as you need, making lists and dictionaries as you need. Once you have a dictionary that resembles what you need, the `json.dumps()` should take care of it.

As people have pointed out in the comments, generally, StackOverflow isn't the place to ask *how* to do something.